# Check password OpenLDAP with pwdGraceUseTime

Tags: openldap, spring-ldap

I am currently working with OpenLDAP. In the LDAP policy, the attribute "pwdGraceAuthnLimit" values 3.
When a user's password is expired, the user still has a grace of 3 times where he can log in. During the grace time, the user must change his password.
To change his password, the user must enter the old password and new password.

The problem is when I try to check the old password.
To check the old password, I use SpringLDAP and the method "authenticate of the class LdapTemplate.(https://docs.spring.io/spring-ldap/docs/current/apidocs/org/springframework/ldap/core/LdapTemplate.html).

Each time I call the method authenticate, an attribute "pwdGraceUseTime" is added in the LDAP for the login. So, the number of grace is decremented by 1 for the login.
I have also tried to use the method which is described in the paragraph 4.2 here (https://www.baeldung.com/spring-ldap) but the result is the same.
I have also tried to delete the attribute "pwdGraceUseTime" for the login but it is not possible, I have an error (NO-USER-MODIFICATION).

Could you tell me if it is possible to check the old password without decrementing the grace number because if there is only one grace left for the login and I call the method authenticate, the account is locked?

Comment: I have no idea obout the Spring LDAP API but don't re-authenticate, just change the password via the replace operation where you supply both the old and the new attribute values. OpenLDAP's password policy will intervene and check that the old value is valid.

Comment: I have tried to do this with the class ModificationItem and with the method modifyAttributes of the class LdapTemplate like this:

`final ModificationItem replacePwd = new ModificationItem(DirContext.REPLACE_ATTRIBUTE, new BasicAttribute(USER_PASSWORD, newPassword));`
`getLdapTemplate().modifyAttributes(getContext().getUserRelativeDn(login), new ModificationItem[] {replacePwd});`

The problem is that the old password is not in the parameters so it is not checked.
How can I only check the old password without doing an authentication?

Comment: You need to provide a DELETE with the old value and an ADD with the new value.

Comment: When I try this code, I have an error:
`final ModificationItem removePwd = new ModificationItem(DirContext.REMOVE_ATTRIBUTE, new BasicAttribute(USER_PASSWORD, oldPassword));
final ModificationItem addPwd = new ModificationItem(DirContext.ADD_ATTRIBUTE, new BasicAttribute(USER_PASSWORD, newPassword));

getLdapTemplate().modifyAttributes(getContext().getUserRelativeDn(login), new ModificationItem[] {removePwd, addPwd});`

The error is [LDAP: error code 16 - modify/delete: userPassword: no such value]

Comment: Which means that the old value supplied was incorrect.

Comment: if I do this:
`DirContext ctx = getLdapTemplate().getContextSource().getContext(userDn, oldPassword);`

Then this code works:
`ctx.modifyAttributes(getContext().getUserRelativeDn(login), new ModificationItem[] {removePwd, addPwd});`

But not this code, I have also the error [LDAP: error code 16 - modify/delete: userPassword: no such value] 
`ctx.modifyAttributes(getContext().getUserRelativeDn(login), new ModificationItem[] {removePwd});`

But I don't know why because the password is the same.

Comment: Which means that the old value supplied was incorrect. Again. You can't get the old password out of LDAP: you only get the hash. The whole point of the exercise is that the *user* has to supply his old password. Trying to do it for him is asinine.

Comment: If it was a wrong password, don't you think I would have instead the error [LDAP: error code 49 - Invalid Credentials]?

Comment: No,, I would expect UNWILLING_TO_PERFORM with text of `Must supply correct old password to change to new one`, and an error code of 4 (PP_mustSupplyOldPassword) in the password policy response control if any. But it *was* a wrong password, can't be anything else the way you got it, and what you're doing makes no sense. Why bother with the old value at all if you're only going to (try to) get it out of LDAP anyway? which you can't do?